# How to use diffusion models to draw on top of image?

Tags: diffusion-models

I am thinking about a pipeline that involves multiple diffusion networks. The first one generates an image from a prompt, a use case that is well-documented in literature. The following networks however should draw on top of the output image from step 1, without altering that image (except for the overdrawings of course), so they would be img2img diffusion networks, conditioned on the input image and with the hard restriction not to alter that input image.

A simple example use case would be a first diffusion model that draws an anime character from a prompt, and a second one that draws the outline of the anime character a lot thicker, and a third one that draws evil-looking eyes on top of the real eyes.

Is there any research as to how to achieve this?

Comment: You have a problem defining "without altering that image" as a "hard restriction", whilst simultaneously describing an alteration to the image. What you seem to be asking for is something that *does* alter an image, but only in a specific way that you intended. Perhaps you could expand on how those "only change this aspect" intentions will be supplied to the model?